# Uso de Variables MySQL desde VB.NET

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Al utilizar una query con variables de MySQL desde VB.NET me surge un error

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.

El problema que tengo es que al intentar utilizar una variable MySQL del estilo
`@sumatoria` en una cadena de `VB.NET` dicha variable es reconocida como un parámetro del `MySqlCommand` y no como parte de la cadena en si misma.
Acá dejo el código que utilizo.

```
dim consulta as string = "SET @sumatoria = 0; SELECT @sumatoria := (@sumatoria + debe - haber) AS 'Saldo' from ccclientes WHERE cliente = 443"
Using con
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(consulta, con)
        Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adp.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Using
```

También intenté así con exactamente el mismo resultado:

```
dim sumas as string = "@sumatoria"
dim consulta as string = "SET " & sumas & " = 0; SELECT " & sumas & " := (" & sumas & " + debe - haber) AS 'Saldo' from ccclientes WHERE cliente = 443"
```

Y también intenté esto:

```
dim consulta as string = "SET @sumatoria = 0; SELECT @sumatoria := (@sumatoria + debe - haber) AS 'Saldo' from ccclientes WHERE cliente = 443"
Using con
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(consulta, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sumatoria", "@sumatoria")
        Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adp.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Using
```

Pero en este caso, el problema es que me pasa la variable como cadena entre comillas `'@sumatoria'` y eso da un error diferente en la consulta.

Si esa misma consulta la realizo directamente en el `phpmyadmin` funciona correctamente, el problema que tengo es: Como evito que la variable de MySQL la tome como un escape de cadena por el `@`?

EDIT: necesito la variable porque en cada línea debo mostrar el saldo acumulado hasta el momento. No quiero mostrar el saldo de cada línea en particular sino el acumulado.

EDIT: Definición de la tabla, volcado de datos y resultado esperado.

```
CREATE TABLE `stack` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `debe` double NOT NULL,
  `haber` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `stack`
--

INSERT INTO `stack` (`id`, `debe`, `haber`) VALUES
(1, 100, 0),
(2, 100, 0),
(3, 100, 0),
(4, 100, 0),
(5, 0, 50),
(6, 100, 0),
(7, 0, 150),
(8, 100, 0),
(9, 100, 0),
(10, 100, 0),
(11, 0, 100),
(12, 100, 0);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `stack`
--
ALTER TABLE `stack`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `stack`
--
ALTER TABLE `stack`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13;
COMMIT;
```

La Consulta: (funciona en PhpMyAdmin pero **NO FUNCIONA** en VB.NET porque el símbolo `@` en`MySqlCommand` espera que defina un parámetro, pero no quiero definir un parámetro, lo que necesito es declarar una variable MySQL)

```
SET @sum = 0; 
SELECT debe, haber, @sum := (@sum + debe - haber) AS 'Saldo' from stack;
```

Resultado Esperado:

[image: Query Results on PhpMyAdmin]

Codigo en VB.NET con la misma consulta:

```
dim query as string = "SET @sum = 0; SELECT debe, haber, @sum := (@sum + debe - haber) AS 'Saldo' from stack;"
using con
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adp.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    end using
end using
```

Resultado en VB.NET

[image]

Esta excepción es lanzada porque VB.NET espera que `@sum` sea definido como un parámetro, pero no es lo que necesito, necesito enviar la consulta para que MySql acepte `@sum` como una variable.
Existe una manera de saltear el hecho que `MySqlCommand` espere que le defina un parámetro y mande la query a MySql tal cual está?
Enviarla entre comillas simples o definir el parámetro no funcionó tampoco, porque en ese caso MySql lo interpreta como cadena y no como variable.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Necesitas la variable? Puedes obtener la suma directamente: `SELECT sum(debe - haber) AS 'Saldo' from ccclientes WHERE cliente = 443`, usa el lector del comando para traer el valor.

Comment: Hola, necesito la variable porque en cada línea debo mostrar el saldo acumulado hasta el momento. De esta manera que me indicas, solo estaría mostrando el saldo de cada línea en particular y no el acumulado. Gracias por tu comentario igual.

Comment: No se si esto te ayude, pero encontre esto https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1201569/How-do-I-parameterized-the-queries-of-VB-NET-code

Comment: Si tienes MySQL 8, el saldo acumulado lo obtienes con `sum(debe - haber) over(order by id) AS 'Saldo'`

Comment: @Sal esa es la respuesta, la podrias agregar como respuesta? OP esta intentando hacer algo que se puede hacer mucho mejor con herramientas "mas modernas"

Comment: @Sal Server version: 5.7.35 MySQL Community Server (GPL) :(

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por tu tiempo, sin embargo la modernidad de las herramientas no siempre depende de nosotros los desarrolladores. Tengo una solución alternativa funcionando, que es la de iterar el DataTable y hacer las sumas línea a línea en este momento. Sin embargo, la pregunta va por otro camino, que es: "Como utilizar variables de MySql desde VB.NET". Agradezco a todos por el interés!!

Comment: en este caso ¿porque no irse por el camino de crear un store procedure que te haga la consulta y en VB.NET usar la sentencia CALL?

Comment: Buen punto.. pero no teniamos esa informacion.. Igual voy a corregir algo de tu pregunta.. No es vb.net quien espera que @algo sea un parametro.. son las librerias de mysql...igual estas cosas, se suelen hacer con SP... pero vale, tal vez haya una forma de solucionarlo...